# Data Modeling : Item With Dimensions (One-to-Many)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, data-modeling

I need suggestions on how to properly model an item record along with all of its corresponding dimensions.
Consider the following:

```
|  ITEM_ID | ITEM_DESCRIPTION | ITEM_PRICE  | SIZE | LENGTH | COLOR
|   SH01   |   POLO SHIRT     |   22.95     | LARGE|        |
|   PA02   |  KHAKI PANTS     |    9.95     |  38  |   32   |
|   BR22   |   BRACELET       |   10.95     |      |        | GREEN
```

All of the items have different dimensions that may/may not be used by other items.  Shirts and pants have sizes and lengths.  The bracelet, however, has only a color.

Also, new dimensions may be necessary as new items are added (weight, pattern, etc.).

I've looked at EAV (entity-attribute-value), but from what I understand, reporting would be a nightmare with such a model.
How can I manage the dimensions for each item?  Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You basically have 4 options, they are discussed [here](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the word 'Dimension' you imply you are building a star schema. The physical representation of these 'optional' attributes is mostly dependent on your query tool and desired performance.

IMHO, in dimensional modelling, you should not be afraid of very wide dimensions, particularly if they make querying easier.

If a user runs a query on *all* product sizes including watches and pants, does it make sense to bucket watches etc. into a N/A size?

EAV is in many ways the opposite of dimensional modelling. dimensional modelling is about making querying as fast and as simple as possible by rearranging data in the ETL process.

Design is often easier if you find a pre proven design approach and stick with it.